# Optimization of code for faster response to touch event

Tags: jquery, performance, font-awesome

I am using font awesome for icons and have them switching on a click (touch) event.
I have this HTML.

```
<i class="fa fa-circle-o hidden-md hidden-lg"></i>
```

And use this jquery to go back and forth.

```
$('body').on('click','.fa-check-circle-o, .fa-circle-o', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-check-circle-o fa-circle-o');
});
```

There is a noticable lag from the number of operations performed:

1. Detect click event
2. Switch class
3. Find the CSS
4. Redraw the CSS

The lag causes users to click twice, thinking their initial click didn't work. How can I make this operation quicker?

(Font awesome is a local file, jquery is cdn, CSS is 6KB, using Angular)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Having `$('body')` come first can be a real drag. Can you put your `<i>`s in a `<div id="someAwesomeID"><!-- <i>'s in here --></div>` and then use `$('#someAwesomeID')` because it will be MUCH faster at least in terms of selector performance.

Comment: for the click latency  https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: I am using views with angular which makes it tricky since it won't recognize an element not on the "master page". This element is embedded in one of the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I was using a click event in jquery when I should have been using touchstart. Now it's working super fast!

```
$('body').on('touchstart click','.fa-check-circle-o, .fa-circle-o', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-check-circle-o fa-circle-o');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better selector for adding the click functionality

```
$('.fa-check-circle-o, .fa-circle-o').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-check-circle-o fa-circle-o');
});
```

Though I think your problem may be the loading of the font awesome font, not the speed of touch event. Just check if it is the speed of the event with an alert or output something to the console. Then atleast you know what the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Simple-Touch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-touch). Read Docs, you can just set an ID to your elements and it works and It highly optimized for touch on devices.